# Trigger database search result with multiple keywords

Tags: php, mysql, html

I have a PHP search script that searches a MySQL database to answer questions. Currently my database is set out like this...

**id**
**question** = what is the time
**answer** = The time is 12:00

This data is then sent to my PHP code:

```
<?php

mysql_connect("localhost","username","password");
mysql_select_db("database");

if(!empty($_GET['q'])){
$query=mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_GET['q']));
$searchSQL="SELECT * FROM questions WHERE `question` LIKE '%{$query}%'  LIMIT 1";
$searchResult=mysql_query($searchSQL);

while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($searchResult)){
$results="{$row['answer']}";
}

echo $results;
}

?>
```

Currently, the users query must contain exactly the same text as the question field. My question is; **how can I make this work so it triggers a certain for several keywords?**

I hope you can understand my question

Comment: Could you give an example of the sort of keywords you'd like to match a particular question with?

Comment: I think that kind of natural language processing is going to be beyond the scope of a SO Q&A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think full test search  index can help
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html SOUNDEX function can be useful in this context too.
You can split query to keywords and generate dynamic SQL but it is inefficient (performance issues SQL injection attacks  )  see http://php.net/manual/en/function.split.php

Alternative is to add table QUESTION_KEYWORD(QUESTION_ID,KEYWORD), split question and search this table to find best QUESTION_ID, but full text search index is more efficient. In fact full text search index uses similar data structure to optimize test search.

Answer (score 0):

For an easy quick-fix based on your comment you could do something as simple as this:

```
// Assuming query string is ?q=make,sponge,cake
$searchSQL="SELECT * FROM questions WHERE ";
$count = 0;
foreach (explode(',', $_GET['q']) as $query) {
  $searchSQL .= "`question` LIKE '%" .mysql_real_escape_string(trim($query)) . "%' ";
  if ($count++ > 0) {
    $searchSQL .= ' OR ';
  }
}

$searchSQL .= ' LIMIT 1';
$searchResult = mysql_query($searchSQL);
```

Comment: You could just reverse the process, ie `q=how,to,make,a,sponge,cake`, if it's ok to be loose with your matching (using `OR`) then that would work. If you want a selective `AND` then I'm afraid it's more like natural language processing as stated above